# GridView Buttons, only one of them is working

Tags: android, gridview

I have a problem with my GridView and buttons inside the gridview. The idea is, the person clicks the button inside each "item" of the grid, and a Dialog Box pops up with text related to that Grid (Which is already inside a textView but Visibility is set to hidden".)

Only the first button inside the GridView works properly, the rest just read "role".

Here is **MyAdapter.java** class

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Players> playerList;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
Button btnRoleReveal;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Players> playerList){
    this.context = context;
    this.playerList = playerList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return playerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout_grid_item, null);


    final Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRoleReveal);
    TextView idTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_id);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_name);
    final TextView roleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_role);

    final String role = roleTextView.getText().toString();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Test")
                    .setMessage(role)
                    .show();
        }
    });


    Players p = new Players();
    p = playerList.get(position);
    idTextView.setText("ID: " + String.valueOf(p.getId()));
    nameTextView.setText("Name: " + String.valueOf(p.getName()));
    roleTextView.setText("Role: " + String.valueOf(p.getRole()));

    return convertView;
}


}
```

I have read that I may need to add buttons programmatically but I am not sure how to approach this. If you need to see any additional code or have any suggestions, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the following line is giving you want you want. I question that it does because 1) the data is taken from a just created view, or, 2) the data is taken from a converted view and what would that data be? Your dialog is going to reflect whatever `role` is at this point regardless of how the `TextView` changes in the future.

```
 final TextView roleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_role);
```

Also, take a look at the rest of the code. This line is not useful since you immediately replace `p`:

```
Players p = new Players();
```

Do you want to set the other values here or do you want to set them before `button.setOnClickListener()` so that `role` is set to the value you want for the dialog? You may want to consider moving these up to the start of `getView()`.

```
p = playerList.get(position);
idTextView.setText("ID: " + String.valueOf(p.getId()));
nameTextView.setText("Name: " + String.valueOf(p.getName()));
roleTextView.setText("Role: " + String.valueOf(p.getRole()));
```

I hope this helps. (btw, you don't need to add the buttons programatically.)